# Discrete valuation rings.

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, reference-request

Given an algebraically closed field $\mathbb F$ of characteristic $p$, let $\mathbb A$ be a discrete valuation ring of characteristic zero having $\mathbb F$ as its residue field ( it does exist, but I don't know a reference).

(1) If $\zeta$ is a primitive cubic root of unity, then $\mathbb A[\zeta]$ is also a discrete valuation ring having $\mathbb F$ as residue field? Moreover, if the characteristic of $\mathbb F$ is not 3, then $\zeta\in\mathbb A$? (What about for a $m^{th}$ root of unity?)

(2) If the characteristic of $\mathbb F$ is not 2, then $\sqrt2\in\mathbb A$?

What could be a good reference to attack these questions?

---

Well, I've found that the answer for (1) and (2) is 'YES'. But it is direct consequence of Henselian Fields. So, the question now becomes the following:

Given an algebraically closed field $\mathbb F$ of characteristic $p$, how to prove that there exists a  Henselian discrete valuation ring of characteristic zero having $\mathbb F$ as its residue field ???

Comment: About the reference: Google "Witt vectors" :)

Comment: And for your questions: you could try to apply Hensel's lemma?

Comment: @Wanderer: please, see the question again, I've edited it...

Comment: This isn't really research level...

Comment: Sometimes I think people apply the "research level" mantra a little too often. MO is very largely for mathematicians who are seeking answers to questions in areas where they are not expert. As Gerry Myerson once said, when it comes to areas outside our domain, we are all at the graduate student level, and I think that reminder might apply here. 

Comment: Repeating the question after being told to look up Witt vectors is what is not research level.

Comment: @a-fortiori: yes, you're certainly right about that. 

Comment: @Keenan Kidwell: This kind of comment is worthless. I am a researcher as you are and my research is about a totally different subject than the present one. 
Your comment is also poor, since in two days I've found many books and papers about Henselian rings concerning about this kind of problem with roots. 
I agree that my first post was in a very specific scenery (square roots and cubic unity roots), but I also would like to learn about this stuff.
You are not being humble with your judgement, even more being an user with a 1k reputation... 

Comment: @a-fortiori: I didn't understand your comment!
Witt vectors doesn't answer the question!

Comment: For any perfect field $\mathbb F$ of characteristic $p$, so in particular for any algebraically closed field, the Witt vectors $W(\mathbb F)$ are a complete, hence Henselian, discrete valuation ring of characteristic 0 having $\mathbb F$ as residue field.

Comment: @a-fortiori: Now I got it. With your phrase I found in the Ido Efart's book the result which guarantee that if we have a Henselian DVR, then we can play this "game" with roots. Thanks!

Comment: Serre's "Corps Locaux" (or Local Fields) is a great reference to look up Witt vectors!

Comment: @Angelo Okay, I rescind my comment. The questions (1) and (2) are exercises if you know something about Henselian DVR's (you want to assume your DVR is Henselian in these) but of course not every mathematician uses these kind of things regularly. I apologize, and did not mean to offend. 